# Making a missing data mapping/graph out of the days missing in a time series

Tags: r, plot, time-series

I have a data frame of the following structure:

```
 df <- read.table(text="ID Time
    58 15-10-2015
    59 16-10-2015
    60 19-10-2015
    61 21-10-2015
    62 26-10-2015
    63 28-12-2015",h=T)
```

I would like to make a missmap based on the days that are not represented, so for example 17-10-2015 and 18-10-2015 would be set as missing data. So would the month of November 2015, etc.

However, I have not found a way to make this visual without compromising the quantities of days missing.

I considered splitting the data into one column for every month to display in in Amelia, but that did not work for the end of months.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This might help: https://njtierney.github.io/r/missing%20data/rbloggers/2015/12/01/ggplot-missing-data/. It shows a way to create missmaps with ggplot.

Comment: Problem is the same, there have to be multiple columns, which makes it difficult when its one series spread over the years.

Comment: I also don't know how to plot your data, which is basically one column. However, I prefer to fill time series gaps using data.frame. An example:

        #change date format to ISO standard.
        df$date <- as.Date(df$Time, format = "%d-%m-%Y")

        #Fill time series
        min_2015 <- as.Date('2015-10-16')
        max_2015 <- as.Date('2015-12-31')
        all_2015 <- data.frame(date = seq(min(min_2015), max(max_2015), by = "day"))
        miss_2015 <- merge(df,all_2015, by = "date", all = TRUE)